# Getting Exception on calling java main function of a class from my jsp file

Tags: java

I'm trying to call main method of a class from my jsp file by passing an argument.I imported the package of the class in my method. but I'm getting run time exception,here is the stacktrace

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.submit_jsp._jspService(submit_jsp.java:99)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

here is the code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="code.*" %>
 <%@ page import="code.utils.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <%
  String message=request.getParameter("message");
  //getting exception in the below line
  PublishSubscribeSample.main(new String[]{message});

  %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It would help if you included the runtime exception you're getting.

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace also.

Comment: Why are you trying to call a `main` method from a jsp? And, here is a fun idea, maybe tell us **what `Exception`** you're getting?

Comment: I'm posting stacktrace